# Mirror PDFs from left to right preferably via the command line?

Tags: pdf

Is it possible to mirror a PDF page, preferably via command line?

By mirroring I don’t mean rotating it, and I don’t mean changing the colors or the page ordering

I mean mirroring the content of a page, so that it appears as if you would look at it from the back. As if it were a printed sheet of paper that is held against the light and viewed from the unprinted side.

So that the contents of the printed side shine through. `abcdef` would then read `fedcba` with the letters also inverted. It doesn’t matter if the data format is changed.

Comment: Suggested edit: you mean "mirror" a PDF? Would technically be feasible by changing the page matrix.

Answer (score 4):

**cpdf (Coherent PDF)** seems like exactly what you are looking for. It is a fantastic piece of command-line freeware (free for non-commercial use) which seems to be not as widely known as it should be for its amazing feature set. See https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries for downloads and links to examples, their extremely comprehensive (and well-written, in my opinion) ~70-page manual, and support. Here is the command you would want (just swap out the sample paths for your use case):

```bsh
cpdf -i "path_to_input_file.pdf" -hflip -o "path_to_output_file.pdf"
```

You can use `-range` to select just some pages of the input file. The `reverse` range will reverse the order of the pages, which may be helpful in this use case.

*Note: cpdf allows for more concise syntaxes than the above, but I included the extra bits for clarity. For example, the following is also valid: `cpdf path_to_input_file.pdf reverse -hflip -o path_to_output_file.pdf`*

Comment: `cpdf junk.pdf -range 2-2  -hflip  -o junkm.pdf` worked to flip one page for me.

Answer (score 1):

Several methods below, but they all involve Adobe commercial products.

**Adobe Acrobat**

Enter Acrobat print to the "Adobe PDF" printer, click the "Properties" button, in the "Layout" tab click on "Advanced",
expand "PostScript Options" and set "Mirrored Output" to "Yes".

[image]

**Adobe InDesign**

Go to Object > Transform > Flip horizontal.

**Adobe Illustrator**

Go to Object > Transform > Reflect.

**Adobe Photoshop or Adobe Photoshop Elements**

You can open .pdf files and you can flip or mirror pages and save them as .pdf or image.

Comment: The first method, "mirrored output" flips the image both horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score -1):

In Pro:

- Select edit pdf
- Right click on page
- Select all
- Right click, Flip options should appear.

Save your doc first in case it doesn't work.

Comment: It might be worth saying the pro edition of what application...